# Will a beforeEach that is outside a describe always complete before the start of a beforeEach that is inside a describe?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs

Is the outer `beforeEach` guaranteed to complete before the inner `beforeEach` starts?

```
let qux;

beforeEach(() => {
  //
  // other synchronous code here
  //
  qux = null;
});

describe('Description', () => {

  beforeEach(() => {
    qux = 0;
    //
    // other synchronous code here
    //
  });

  it('Predicate', () => {
    expect(qux).toEqual(0);
  });
});
```

In other words, is the above test guaranteed to pass?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the outer `beforeEach` is guaranteed to complete before the inner `beforeEach` starts:

`Jest` finds all the `before` functions for a spec by starting where the spec is defined and walking up the parents [here](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/f0f2ee3fc9078074dcf30790ef00dc3ecbc230a0/packages/jest-jasmine2/src/jasmine/Env.js#L113-L118) and returning the reversed list [here](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/f0f2ee3fc9078074dcf30790ef00dc3ecbc230a0/packages/jest-jasmine2/src/jasmine/Env.js#L121).

The `before` functions, test, and `after` functions get put in an array [here](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/f0f2ee3fc9078074dcf30790ef00dc3ecbc230a0/packages/jest-jasmine2/src/jasmine/Spec.js#L117).

Each function is wrapped by [`mapper`](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/f0f2ee3fc9078074dcf30790ef00dc3ecbc230a0/packages/jest-jasmine2/src/queue_runner.js#L37-L80) which returns a Promise that *does not resolve until the function completes, the test is cancelled, an error occurs, or the timeout is reached*, and the resulting Promises are chained together by the `reduce` [here](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/f0f2ee3fc9078074dcf30790ef00dc3ecbc230a0/packages/jest-jasmine2/src/queue_runner.js#L82-L85).

So unless there is an error, a timeout, or the test is cancelled the `beforeEach` functions will run to completion in order and the test above will pass.

Answer (score 1):

There is some information in the PR which added the support for multiple beforeEach / afterEach calls (https://github.com/qunitjs/qunit/pull/1188/files) - so as long as your operations are synchronous you should be fine - you can verify that also in the test cases in the above PR.

Comment: The first comment says this: "outer and earlier-declared before/beforeEach functions run before​ inner and later-declared ones." That means the start times for the `beforeEach` are guaranteed, but still doesn't guarentee that the outer ones finish before the inner ones start.

Comment: If I understand correctly, Node is single threaded, so assuming that we are not running asynchronous code, it seems safe to assume that a function that starts first must end before the one that starts second begins. Does that seem right?

Comment: yup - all sync functions (all the way down) are executed in 1 loop tick (up to a given max call stack size, I think it was 984)

Comment: You linked to the qunitjs docs. Is jest somehow based on qunitjs?